# EF: Como retornar apenas algumas colunas do banco de dados?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, api

Estou tendo problemas para retornar uma coleção de objetos do banco com apenas algumas colunas selecionadas. Procurei várias soluções pela web e a grande maioria apresentou a solução abaixo, fazendo um Where e logo após um Select para selecionar as colunas desejadas:

```
 public override async Task<IEnumerable<KeyType>> GetAllAsync(Guid? userId)
    {
        try
        {
            return await _context.Set<KeyType>()
                .Where(keytype => keytype.UserId.Equals(userId))
                .Select(x => new KeyType
                {
                    x.Name,
                    x.Description,
                    x.UserId
                }).ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Porém ele está dando o erro : "Não é possível inicializar o tipo "KeyType" com um inicializador de coleta porque ele não implementa "System.Collections.IEnumerable". Qual será o erro? Qual seria o tipo correto neste caso? Obrigado.

Comment: pq não cria uma classe com as três propriedades que precisa?

Comment: Bom, até pensei fazer DTOs mas achei que ficaria muito código repetido até porque são muitas classes.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido: apenas mudei o `Task<IEnumerable<KeyType>>` para `Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>>` e alterei a assinatura na interface a qual ela implementa.